# Fail to connect to Microsoft sql server

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to connect a `php script` to a Microsoft SQL Server, Additionally I'm doing some testing on my own to learn more about php and servers.

```
if(function_exists("sqlsrv_connect"))
{
    echo "exists<br/>";
}else
{
    die("does not exist<br/>");
}
$serverName = "myTestServer";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"test_name", "UID"=>"testUser", "PWD"=>"testPwd");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
if($conn)
{
    echo "sucessful";
}
else
{
    echo "failed ";
}
```

The output is:

```
exists
failed
```

Therefore I can see that the `.dll` was installed as intended. Am I missing something else? or could this be a problem in the server properties?

Comment: Check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php) to see how to properly display the full error message -- the first example shows you how to use [sqlsrv_errors()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-errors.php).

Comment: Thanks! Does this error say that I need to have a sql server client programm on my local PC for connecting? Cause I am trying to connect to another pc who has sql server installed, but I don't...

Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -49 [code] => -49 [2] => This extension requires either the Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Native Client (SP1 or later) or the Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Native Client ODBC Driver to communicate with SQL Server. Neither of those ODBC Drivers are currently installed. Access the following URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 [...]

Comment: Yes, exactly that. You need a supported SQL Server ODBC driver installed on whatever machine is running the PHP code. You can install the ODBC driver (and the client utilities, if you want, but they're not needed for a PHP connection) separately from SQL Server itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever a failure occurs with a SQLSRV PHP function, call [sqlsrv_errors](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-errors.php) to find out the root cause. In your case, it seems you don't have the correct SQL Server ODBC drivers installed on the PHP server. Install the drivers as recommended by your error message, and things should improve.